# How to get an object surface while it is rotating in the video

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a video with a mango is rotating and I get stuck at getting all it's surface to one picture (like the earth). Can any body have any idea for me? All I want is just get all the surface (like panorama but only the mango rotate)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVYu8.png)

Comment: My first idea was photo stitching but this probably won't work out of the box. Now, I had a new idea: Imagine your video as 3d image cube (3rd axis is time) like in CT images. If you swap x and time axis you might get what you want. E.g. In each video frame, read only the middle column of image and add it output image. (This is actually like a line scanner.)

Comment: but how do I stop exactly when the object(with different sizes) rotated 360 degree?

Comment: No mind. I would consider this as 2nd part. Once I had solved the 1st part, I would select manually from which to which frame I get a 360° view and whether it provides an acceptable result. _Then_ I would start to think about 2nd part... ;-)

Comment: I must admit that it's long time ago that I did image processing and I never reached professional experience. However, if you reached 360° then you should get similar columns to the beginning. May be, now, techniques of image stitching (or some other kind of matching) can be applied.

Comment: And, please, don't forget: The number of frames for a ful 360° view doesn't depend on object size but only on rotation speed. ;-) (Though, the rotation speed might be adjusted dependent on object size...)